# Why not pass value in this function in c

Tags: c

I make a function for allocating memory for concatenating n strings. And I pass my pointer for allocating the memory, but when returning the function the pointer is NULL. Why has this happened???

```
char_t * StrAllocMultipleCat(
char_t *            sDst,
uint32_t *          udDstLen,
const  char_t *     sStr,
...
)
{
    uint32_t                udSize = 1;
    va_list                 vaArgs;


    sDst = VNULL;
    va_start( vaArgs, sStr );

    while( sStr != VNULL )
    {
        uint32_t        udStrLen = strlen( sStr );


        if ( udStrLen )
        {
            char_t *                  sTmp;


            sTmp = (char_t *)realloc( sDst, udSize + udStrLen );
            if ( sTmp )
            {
                sDst = sTmp;
                strcpy( &sDst[ udSize - 1 ], udStrLen + 1, sStr );
                udSize += udStrLen;
            }
        }

        sStr = va_arg( vaArgs, const char_t * );
    }

    va_end( vaArgs );


    if ( udDstLen )
        *udDstLen = (uint32_t)( udSize - 1 );

    printf( "sDst: %X\n", (uint32_t)(void *)sDst );
    printf( "sDst: %s\n", sDst );


    return sDst;
}
```

This is a sample code

```
uint16_t    ulPosLen;
char_t *    pStr = NULL;
char_t *    pStr2= NULL;



pStr2 = StrAllocMultipleCat( pStr, &udLen, "Hola ", "Mundo ", "Bonito", VNULL );
printf( "<%X>\n", (uint32_t)(void *)pStr2 );
printf( "<%X>\n", (uint32_t)(void *)pStr );
printf( "<%s> <%u>\n", pStr, udLen );

free( pStr );
free( pStr2 );

return 1;
```

This is the output of sample code, and you can see that sDst parameter have the correct value inside the function and the return work fine too. But the pStr parameter point to null. This is very strange.

```
sDst: 10BFE78
sDst: Hola Mundo Bonito
<10BFE78>
<0>
<(null)> <17>
```

Comment: Dear Xing, Thanks for your answer and we make the function that you say... Only I want understand why not work the pointer parameter and now you help me!!!!

Comment: As already pointed out, the value of `pStr` is passed to the function, which overwrites the `NULL` value *local to the function*, but the original `pStr` is never modified, so it is still `NULL` as shown when you tried to print the string you imagine it points to, but does not. The `free( pStr );` only works because `free` helpfully does nothing when passed `NULL`, i.e. there was no memory allocated which can be `free`d.

Comment: @xing:  Looks like you should post that as a complete answer instead of a comment.

Comment: `char_t * StrAllocMultipleCat(
const  char_t *     sStr,
...
)`